# Why SO recently began removing formatting whitespace within code blocks?

Tags: bug, status-declined, code-formatting

Recently I've noticed that formatting whitespace in code blocks appears to be removed:

```
line1 - next line is prepended by six spaces
      line2 supposed to be indented but isn't
```

which the graphic snapshot below is clearly demonstrating: 
[image: graphic snapshot]
Apparently, a some breaking change took place recently on SO as old posts having code blocks are similarly got stripped of formatting whitespace. This UI behavior creates a major headache for languages like **`F#`** where whitespace is syntactically significant.

Is it a bug or feature? And what would be the remedy apart from embedding code block images or placing snippets at foreign sites like `pastebin`?

This is using IE 10 **Compatibility Mode** on Windows 8.

Comment: Please provide a link that shows the issue. Even in your example, the line that is supposed to be indented... well... is.

Comment: For example, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101329/f-sequence-comparison/17101734#17101734) although I believe the embedded image demonstrates the problem quite clearly.

Comment: All the code seems to be formatted fine in the link.

Comment: Can you see if all JavaScript is loading and executing without error on your browser? (what browser _are_ you using, by the way?)

Comment: I know that **it is** indented, but the fact that ... well, maybe in some browsers,... it **visually** looks not indented creates a major headaches for understanding the code for certain languages.

Comment: **What** browsers? I believe most of the users **can**, **visually**, see things **as intended**. Please give us some **specifics** that we can work with. Like - what browser are you using? What version? Are you getting any issues with JavaScript?

Comment: The effect is the same in IE10 and FireFox 21.0 on Win8. Lemme check how it looks on Win7 for other browsers...

Comment: I can't reproduce on Windows 7 using `Chrome 27.0.1453.110 m` or IE 10.

Comment: I can see now that the effect, in fact, is limited to IE10 ONLY on Win8. I'll withdraw the question in a minute as I can definitely live with this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't withdraw it. I'll drop the [meta-tag:status-norepro] so we know what to look for.

Comment: Tried it in Win 8 on Chrome and IE10. Indentations show as intended and indented.

Comment: @Gene - is IE by chance not using standards mode?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. Turning on 'Compatibility View' in IE10 (Win8) shows the problem of missing indentation.

Answer (score 7):

```
I am trying
   to reproduce this using 4 spaces
```

```
using pre
    for example
```

`or code element all
       alone by iteself`

```
or using pre
  and code together.
```

The only one that displays an issue is the line that is `<code></code>` by iteself.

---

If you see at least two of the above code sections on a single line, please comment with the browser, OS and version you are using.

Comment: Only on the second snippet the second line is visually indented. Environment is IE 10.0.9200.16384 on Windows8 Pro x64. IE is in standard mode.

Comment: Yup, as @doubleDown noted the problem is tied to Compatibility Mode of IE10 on Win8. You may want to check JavaScript console to see the source of the problem. And thank you for fantastic resolution time!!

Answer (score 1):

For more consistent behaviour you should use 4 spaces (rather than code/pre tags).